# Specify output tray/mailbox using javax.print

Tags: java, printing

I'm trying to print on a printer full of functionality (Kyocera TASKalfa 5501i), having a mailbox add-on with 7 outputs installed. I want to print to each of those outputs indiviually using Java on a server. Because my application runs on a remote server, Java has no UI available to, for example, open the drivers default preferences-window and select the output-tray there. Until now i got all attributes working, that are in the `javax.print.attribute.standard` package, but i have no idea how to select the output-tray.

I searched nearly the entire internet for a solution. Does anyone have an idea how to select the output-tray/mailbox or pass, any non-default parameter to the printer without having to implement the complete printing-stack from bottom up?

Kind regards.

Comment: I take it you have tried [MediaTray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/MediaTray.html)?

Comment: Yes i tried MediaTray. It's working to specify the input tray, but not for the output tray.

Comment: Looks like you’re not the only one who wants this.  The standard print attributes are based on IPP 1.1, which [was published in September 2000](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2911).  Just a few months later, [another printing attribute, "output-bin", was proposed](http://ftp.pwg.org/pub/pwg/candidates/cs-ippoutputbin10-20010207-5100.2.pdf).  In theory, you can create your own subclass of [EnumSyntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/EnumSyntax.html) which implements PrintRequestAttribute and whose getName() method returns "output-bin".

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i tried today towards the end of work. I just used `printer-output-tray` instead of `output-bin`. Will try this one tomorrow and let you know how it worked out.

Comment: After testing a lot and analyzing the `Win32*.java` implementations, i have to say that, with the default JDK functionality, there is not way to pass custom attributes to the printer. Every attributes class is checked for being one of the classes contained in `javax.print.attribute.standard`. Any other attributes are thrown away.

Comment: That is frustrating, especially considering the [javax.print.attribute documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/package-summary.html) says: “The Java Print Service API is designed so that vendors can … define new attribute categories representing the vendor printer's proprietary capabilities not already supported by the standard attributes.”  I guess “vendor” means JRE implementor.  That said, support for output-bin seems like a reasonable RFE to submit…

Comment: Because most of the printers are network printers and tho support IPP, i finally used a modified version of Cups4j to resolve my problem. The additional advantage is, that the software is now independent of drivers. Thank you for your help!

Comment: RFE: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8314070.  PR: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/16166.  At time of writing this, both pending.   Specifically, the PR does not (yet) address all OSs.  Furthemore, Windows may prove much more difficult, quoting a MSDN post: ""'Output tray" is a printer-specific property [with] no way to programmatically set an output tray, since there is no generic way of doing it via .NET (or even Win32  via the `DEVMODE` structure).  The only way to set it is to allow the user to choose it via the provided printer dialog [...]""